# How to create a domain-specific graph with python from CSV-data?

Tags: python, graph, visualization, finance, quantitative-finance

I need help to find a way to visualize the a graph with the following data:

The graphic shows distribution development in the Treasury bond futures market. Value areas from the night and day sessions are organized in a special format.

[image: graph]

The "value ranges" consists oft two data points: High and Low.

Distribution is on the vertical axis.

Development, when it occurs, will be shown on the horizontal axis. If the value range **`( H - L )`** is higher or lower than the previous session, the rectangle belongs on the vertical axis.

Sideways rotation is on the horizontal axis. If value is unchanged or
partially overlaps the previous session, the rectangle belongs on the
horizontal axis.

The data can be loaded from a **`.CSV`** file.

I have a basic python understanding, but no experience in data visualisation.

I know how to read in CSV-data in python and how to show/plot data with **`matplotlib`** and **`pandas`** in standard Candlestick Charts, but I don't know how to create the rectangles and the domain-specific behaviour.

Which library should I use `pandas`, MATLAB, `ggplot` or none of them? Which way would be the best to solve the task?

Comment: You want to use one of the many Python graphviz interfaces, such as [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz/](graphviz) or [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot/](pydot). graphviz is specifically designed for making figures like this. If you have specific questions after trying one of those please post a new question.

Comment: Thank you! I needed a starting point, and now I have something I can look at! Greets Chris

Comment: **Welcome to Chris to the worlds of StackOverflow!** You may decide to add a sample CSV-file ( showing the data ) to use for the futures graph-generation and rather remove the last paragraph, as the **StackOverflow Community Netiquette** strongly recommends to **avoid discussions on subjective preferences** to use / not use any library / module / framework / tool etc. Let's focus on the process of graph generation, that is okay. Best answers are collected, once your previous work is being shown, declaring what have you tried so far and where does your approach collide or has problems to solve.